# SSRS Grouping by value ranges: change scope when selecting value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

Currently developing a report that groups items by value range. Using fictional data to describe the situation:

[image: Visual representation]

I'm trying to get this desired output, but I cannot use aggregate functions (Sum, Avg) when grouping items. Is there any way to group the ranges on the parent (order) level while retaining the child (order line) data? Any help would be appreciated.

Currently when I try to sum up the data, the sum of the order line is used (which is equal to the value and of no use to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this at the dataset level. Either by using a separate dataset with Order Totals and the [SSRS 2008R2 `lookup` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) or by adding an Order Total column to the current dataset.

In these you could either get the group value ("1 to 10", "11 to 20"...) or the actual order total and create the grouping in the Group By formula in the SSRS group.